# What's the lighest version of emacs for Ostro x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu?

Tags: linux, build

Using Ostro on [#IntelMaker #Joule](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23IntelMaker%20%23Joule%20%40Mcnst), I've downloaded the earliest version of emacs available from https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/emacs/, and tried running configure, but it failed with a message that emacs wasn't ported to the platform yet.

```
root@intel-corei7-64:~/emacs/emacs-21.4# ./configure 
creating cache ./config.cache
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure: error: Emacs hasn't been ported to `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu' systems.
Check `etc/MACHINES' for recognized configuration names.
root@intel-corei7-64:~/emacs/emacs-21.4# cd ..
```

If I just want an emacs-like text editor, and don't have a package manager, what's the quickest way to get an emacs-compatible editor going?

Size-wise, `emacs-21.4a.tar.gz` is only 19M, but `emacs-25.1.tar.gz` is already 59M.

What was the earliest version that had support for `x86_64`?

Comment: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ErsatzEmacs

Comment: @npostavs, I've tried compiling mg, but it appears to depend on libbsd, but installing `libbsd` doesn't seem to make it detect it.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, Emacs is surprisingly fast to build, so, building even the latest version appears to take less time than the time it takes to run the `./configure` script!

Comment: Building the release tarballs is fairly quick because they already include the compiled lisp files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some lightweight editor like [mg](https://homepage.boetes.org/software/mg/) as a replacement for emacs.

Comment: No, [`mg`](http://bxr.su/o/usr.bin/mg/) has too many dependencies on unbranded Linux, and cannot be built easily.